# Ubuntu Appliance RaspPi4b Firmware- Keyboard & Mouse Don't Work

Tags: ubuntu-core

I am trying to install the Adguard Home Ubuntu Appliance image on an SD card to boot on a raspberry pi 4b.

- In the beginning it didn't boot up, so I fixed it by manually modifying both the start4.elf and fixup4 files.
- Now it boots and gives me the line: "Press Enter to Configure". But I can't use the keyboard to press ENTER nor is there a mouse cursor. Note that the mouse lights do turn on. I tried adding the following files but no success!
  Here are the files I tried so far in different combinations:
  fixup4.dat, fixup4cd.dat, fixup4db.dat, fixup4x.dat, start4.elf, start4cd.elf, start4db.elf, start4x.elf, bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb, bcm2711-rpi-cm4.dtb, bcm2711-rpi-cm4-io.dtb

There must be some file im missing that should fix the issue? Note that I used the latest imager_1.8.5.exe and the latest adguard ubuntu appliance file (adguard-home-core18-pi.img.xz). I'm afraid playing around with more files might damage my pi device, especially that im no expert on this!

Any advice is welcome really,
Thanks, good day!